# Building ros_control on Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-hydro, tinyxml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm trying to build ros_control on Hydro following the steps [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control).

First of all when I use `sudo apt-get install ros_control ros_controllers` apt-get tell me it's impossible for him to find the packages.

But then when I try to build from source using those commands :

```
cd CATKIN_WORKSPACE/src
wstool init
wstool merge https://raw.github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/hydro-devel/ros_control.rosinstall
wstool update
```

Then I use `catkin_make` and I have two kind of errors during the process :

First :

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package cmake_modules.

Set cmake_modules_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
file for cmake_modules.  The file will have one of the following names:

cmake_modulesConfig.cmake
cmake_modules-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
ros_controllers/gripper_action_controller/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

Second :

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package cmake_modules.

Set cmake_modules_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
file for cmake_modules.  The file will have one of the following names:

cmake_modulesConfig.cmake
cmake_modules-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
ros_control/transmission_interface/CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


CMake Error at ros_control/transmission_interface/CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package):
Could not find module FindTinyXML.cmake or a configuration file for package
TinyXML.

Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindTinyXML.cmake or set TinyXML_DIR to
the directory containing a CMake configuration file for TinyXML.  The file
will have one of the following names:

TinyXMLConfig.cmake
tinyxml-config.cmake



CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:156 (message):
catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'TinyXML' which must be find_package()-ed
before.  If it is a catkin package it can be declared as CATKIN_DEPENDS
instead without find_package()-ing it. 
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
ros_control/transmission_interface/CMakeLists.txt:40 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Or I think tinyXML is installed on my system as I have `libtinyxml-dev` and `libtinyxml2.6.2` already installed

Any help is appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141151/building-ros_control-on-hydro/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on 2014-03-17**:
can I use this package in groovy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing the ros-hydro-ros-control and ros-hydro-ros-controllers ubuntu packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-control ros-hydro-ros-controllers
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-03-17**:
To complement Austin's answer, your attempt to do a source build failed because the `cmake_modules` package is missing (which is causing the two reported errors). You can make sure that a package's dependencies are satisfied by running `rosdep install ros_control ros_controllers`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem too, the solution is simply to install the `ros-hydro-cmake-modules` package.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-cmake-modules
```

---

Originally posted by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) with karma: 96 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3